# Define a heading style command, which ignores leading white space if it is used at the beginning of an environment

Tags: environments, conditionals, vertical-spacing

I want to define a kind of heading, that i can use in a shaded environment. I want this "heading" have a bit of leading vertical space, but would like to eliminate this space if the command is used at the beginning of the environment. Defining the "heading" command or the environment is not the problem, only of this conditional `if at start of environment` is doable, and if yes, then how. The space before "**Beginning of Env**" is what I'm hoping to automatically get rid of.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{framed,graphicx,xcolor,lipsum}

\newcommand{\grayboxparagraph}[1]{\par\medskip\bgroup\bfseries #1\egroup\par\nopagebreak}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.85}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \begin{shaded}
    \grayboxparagraph{Beginning of Env}
    \lipsum[2]
    \grayboxparagraph{Just Somewhere in the middle}
    \lipsum[3]
  \end{shaded}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Brute force method (all I know): Define two macros, instead of just one, for your grayboxparagraph. Different skips at top. Then start the env with one macro, and follow with the other. This does not automatically detect whether the paragraph is first in the box, but if necessary you could try adding a boolean that is set when you enter the env. When it is set, the first macro is used. That macro unsets the boolean, so that the second macro is used thereafter.

Comment: @rallg Good idea, I'll give this a try.

Comment: I ended up defining the environment with a parameter which I put the box heading in, if present. I could then find all the instances where an empty box heading was followed by a heading, and merge them.